# Does a tube based HF transmitter need an antenna tuner?

Tags: antenna, hf, antenna-tuner

With the adjustments on a transmitter such as a Yaesu FT-101E, is there any purpose for an antenna tuner, or can you accomplish the same thing by adjusting the loading and other controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original [Yaesu FT-101 tuning instructions](http://foxtango.org/ft101/graphics/Transmitter%20Tune%20UP.JPG) state the following:

> *Do not use antennas which are untuned or exhibit an SWR of more than 2:1*.

An external antenna tuner can usually work with a much broader mismatch range. If you have a "random wire" or otherwise untuned antenna, a tuner is clearly required. A slight mismatch (2:1 or less) can be handled by the tube amplifier's controls.

The same advice will apply to other tube finals.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe an antenna tuner is needed if the power levels are 100 W or less. Doesn't your manual tell you how to attach to an antenna and how to insure that power is going to the antenna? I remember tuning the power out to a light bulb and then attaching the antenna. Anyone else remember that?

Comment: This isn't true, power level has no relevance on whether a tuner is required. Even at five watts, an untuned and mismatched antenna can damage your transmitter.

Comment: Back in the early 1960s with my Eico 720 (PA, 6146B) I never owned a tuner.  In fact, I never knew anyone who owned a tuner.  And, that included a lot of young hams like myself.  I had a 40 meter dipole that was short as I did not have enough room for the full size.  However, during my Novice year, I had a couple of thousand contacts using my Eico transmitter tuned into that antenna.  SWR?  No one cared.  My output power was officially 75 watts (then the legal limit for Novice) but I ran full bore producing 90 watts.  However, that is 90 watts DC input as they measured power in those days.

Comment: Yes, I know, this post is three years old.